# Vue Js models collections and rendering fetch data

Tags: javascript, collections, model, vuejs3, rendering

Hello I have had an on going issue with getting VUEJS 3 to render the output of a fetch collection.
this is a VUEJS component that loads it's own content by calling the collections fetch.

**Template**

```
<template>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
        <template v-if="listings.loading">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="spinner"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <tr v-for="list in listings.models" :key="list.id">
            <td>
              <i class="fab fa-angular fa-lg"></i>
              <strong>{{list.$.title}}</strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</template>
```

**VUEJS setup**
this is stripped down and simplified to keep the code easy to read, however the way the collection is created manipulated and returned is the same.

```
import {ListingList} from "../model";
import {useUserStore} from "../store";
import {
  onMounted,
} from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Listinglist",
  props: {
    title: String,
  },
  setup() {
    // Listinglist is a collection of listing models
    const listings = new ListingList()
    
    listings.fetch().then((data) => {
        // this logs an array as expected.
       console.log(data.response.data)
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
    });
    
    return {
      listings
    }
  },
}
```

[VUEJS Debugger showing the loaded collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUyUj.png)

I have used various ways within Javascript, I've used OnMount and also wrapping the collection in reactive however it never renders the table and just shows the spinner. looking at the console the collection has models and the loading property is false. I'm new the Vue but not coding and normally would work these things out but this one has got me truly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Vue to track changes in your variable, you have to make it reactive: use Vue's `ref()` or `reactive()` functions.

Try this:

```
const listings = ref(new ListingList())

listings.fetch().then((data) => {
    listings.value = data.response.data
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error)
});
```

I would recommend to check related page in [Vue's documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html).

Comment: I did try and return the list in reactive and ref neither solutions worked for me, that was prior to posting this question. I was scraping the idea of using vue-mc and have being writing composable modules which indeed return reactive objects. Also `listings.value = data.response.data` is wrong as it's a collection so this just replaces itself with an array, secondly `listings.fetch()` it would have to be `listings.value.fetch()` I believe.